# 60VAC resistive load (heater) on 220VAC?

Tags: voltage, resistive-load

I need to run a ceramic fiber heater (Watlow part number vc401a06a, [datasheet](https://www.instrumart.com/assets/ceramic_datasheet.pdf)) at 220VAC. This particular part is rated at 60VAC, for 220W. Can I safely use this on 220VAC, if I'll be controlling it with an appropriate SSR? I'm currently using it on 115VAC with no problems, but I want to make sure I can use it on 220VAC. My alternative is to incorporate a step-down transformer and I really don't want to do that.

Comment: That's a peak power more than an order of magnitude higher than rated. You might get away with it using a phase control but I bet the heater life is significantly compromised with an SSR and say 2-3 second cycle. Why are you not asking Watlow's application engineers this question?? Also, if the SSR fails, your heater is toast really fast.

Comment: @Sphero I did ask Watlow, I'm still waiting on a response. They're notoriously slow at responding to inquiries.

Comment: If you're using closed-loop control, it will run flat out at full power while it's heating. Better get the transformer or get a replacement heater rated at 220VAC.

Comment: If SSR means a simple Solid State Relay, no.  You'd need to introduce some sort of rapidly-switched power controller, similar to an incandescent light dimmer, then adjust it so that no more than 220W was consumed by the heater.  (Probably a little tricky to figure out how to measure 220W, though.)

Answer (score 3):

If this thing is rated for 60 V max, then no, you shouldn't run it at 220 V.  You shouldn't even run it at 115 V.

The power dissipated by a resistor is proportional to the square of the current.  (220 V)²/(60 V)² = 13.4.  That much more power is quite likely to damage something.  You will get a little bit of forgiveness because the resistivity of most material used for heaters goes up with temperature.  But, a factor of 13.4 is so large that this isn't going to save you.  The resistance might be a few percent higher - for a short time until it either cathes fire, melts, blows up, or otherwise suffers some irreversible catastrophic loss of function.

Bottom line: **Bad idea**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you suggest a step-down that will go from 220 to 60 VAC?

Comment: At 220 watts, I'd suggest a pair of 220 to 120 step-down transformers hooked up with the output of one feeding the input of the second. If you use transformers with multiple taps which allow fine control of the secondary voltage, you should be able to get just the voltage you need. If you can live with a nominal 55 volt output, just as an example, at http://www.220-electronics.com/step-down-voltage-converters.html you can get what you need for $30 (plus shipping).

Comment: I need to modify the previous comment. If you go the two-transformer route, I'd recommend the second transformer (the 110 to 55 unit) be a higher-power unit, such as 500 or 600 watts, in order to handle the greater current which goes along with lower voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good approach. It will expose the element to gross temperature cycling even if you manage to control the input, and things will go poof in case of a problem.

I suggest you get ahold of a suitable step-down transformer, such as this [toroidal type](http://shop.plitron.com/specs/0770XX201.pdf) from [Plitron](http://shop.plitron.com/shopdisplaycategories.asp):

[image]

You just need to wire the 115VAC primaries in series and the 30VAC secondaries in series. (2-3 and 6-7).

> 300VA Power Transformer
>
> Output: 2 X 30VAC @ 5.00A
>
> Product ID: 077017201
>
> Weight: 7.50 lbs
>
> Height: 4.6 inches
>
> Width: 9.9 inches
>
> Length: 9.9 inches
>
> US$101.65